# How to merge different rows in Excel based on a condition?

Tags: excel, vba

How do I merge different rows in an Excel sheet into one row without losing any data by testing if the content of one of the column is equal. Also the merged rows should be treated as one single row. For example:

```
  row  Title1   Title2
   1     1        sdf
   2     1        dsf
   3     2        dsf
   4     3        dsaf
   5     3        asd
```

I want the above Excel sheet to become like so:

```
  row  Title1   Title2
   1     1        sdf
                  dsf
   2     2        dsf
   3     3        dsaf
                  asd
```

Comment: Making a `Pivot Table` out of your original data is fastest.

Comment: @L42 can you please eloborate

Comment: I misinterpret your requirement. I suggest you use Dictionary or an array to store your values first before you do the merging. The idea is you need to preserve your data in the background while doing the merge so you can re-populate the merge cells with the original values passed to an array or Dictionary.

Comment: @L42 I will try that and let you know what happens

Answer (score 0):

`=IF (Logic_Test, Value_if_True, Value_if_False)` so for you it would be something like this in the `D column` `=IF(A1=A2, “=A1&B1&C1” , NA())`

Comment: This did not solve my problem. The merged cells remained to be in different rows which is not what I want